# Different Condition checks supported in binding.gyp

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I am very new to nodejs addons. I would like to know what are the different conditions that can be checked in binding.gyp. I am aware of checking the os platform using

```
'conditions': [
          ['OS=="linux"', {}
          ]
```

What are the other variables available similar to OS? Is it possible to know the version of nodejs in the similar way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are some variables, [predefined in GYP](https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md#Predefined-Variables).

Node-gyp sets another variables in generated `build/config.gypi` file. Unfortunately there is no variable for the Node.js version in that file. But you can evaluate it in your GYP file with [command expansion](https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md#Command-Expansions):

```
{
    'variables': {
        'node_version': '<!(node -e "console.log(process.versions.node)")',
    },
   # .. rest of GYP file
}
```

Comment: The URLs you've attached is dead. Please modify or remove.